# How to pass props to child from parent with a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props

I have a parent component that use a map to render child components with some data. I need to pass the data as props to the child component but when i pass them i cant access them in child component. this.props.children prop has the props i need but is there a better way to pass them to the child component?

**Parent component**

```
class Home extends Component {

  renderArtCards = (artCardArray) => {
    return (artCardArray.map((artCard, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <ArtCard>
            title={artCard.title}
            image={artCard.image}
            description={artCard.description}
            price={artCard.price}
          </ArtCard>
        </div>
      )
    })
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="row no-gutters justify-content-end pageTitleRow">
          <div className="pageTitle">Home</div>
        </div>
        <div className="artCardsRow">
          <Masonry
            className={'masonryStyle'}
            options={masonryOptions}>
            {this.renderArtCards(artCards)}
          </Masonry>
        </div>

      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

**Child component**

```
class ArtCard extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.children)
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Card className="artCardBody">
                    <CardMedia
                        className="artCardMedia"
                        image={this.props.image}
                        title={this.props.title}
                    />
                    <CardContent>
                        <div className="row artCardTitleRow">
                            <div className="artCardTitle">{this.props.title}</div>
                            <div className="artCardPrice">Rs.{this.props.price}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="text-muted">{this.props.description}</div>
                    </CardContent>
                </Card>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

I need to access props in child component with this.props.xxxx

Comment: title, image, description, price should be inside opening tag ArtCard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The props go *inside* the `<Name ... >`. You currently pass no props to `<ArtCard>`, just text as its children.

Comment: This worked. I should have checked that. Thank you very much

Comment: `this.props.children` doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a `class` for your child component so let do this (dumb component):

```js
const ArtCard = ({ image, title, price, description }) => (
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Card className="artCardBody">
                    <CardMedia
                        className="artCardMedia"
                        image={image}
                        title={title}
                    />
                    <CardContent>
                        <div className="row artCardTitleRow">
                            <div className="artCardTitle">{title}</div>
                            <div className="artCardPrice">Rs.{price}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="text-muted">{description}</div>
                    </CardContent>
                </Card>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```